# C++ Program skipping second fuction call

Tags: c++, function, reference, arguments, pass-by-reference

I have a problem in my C++, I call a first funtion (verif) which runs very well and then when I try to run an other one (dateIncrement), she just dont run and it skips to the next if, I saw it with the debugger, here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool verif(int day, int month, int year) {
    bool verifStatus;
    bool month31;
    bool month30;
    bool anneeBis;
    bool feb29;
    bool feb;
    month31 = ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) && day > 0 && day < 32);
    month30 = ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day > 0 && day < 31);
    anneeBis = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
    feb = (month == 2 && day > 0 && day < 29);
    feb29 = ((month == 2 && day == 29) && anneeBis);
    verifStatus = (month31 || month30 || feb || feb29);
    return verifStatus;
}

int dateIncrement(int day, int month, int year) {
    bool month31;
    bool month30;
    bool anneeBis;
    bool feb29;
    bool feb;
    bool dec;
    bool dec31;
    month31 = ((month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10) && day > 0 && day < 32);
    month30 = ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && day > 0 && day < 31);
    anneeBis = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
    feb = (month == 2 && day > 0 && day < 29);
    feb29 = ((month == 2 && day == 29) && anneeBis);
    dec = (month == 12 && day > 0 && day < 31);
    dec31 = (month == 12 && day == 31);

    if (month31) {
        if (day == 31) {
            day = 1;
            month++;
        }

        if (day < 31) day++;
    }

    if (month30) {
        if (day == 30) {
            day = 1;
            month++;
        }

        if (day < 30) day += 1;
    }

    if(feb) day += 1;
    if (feb29) {
        day = 1;
        month++;
    }

    if (dec31) {
        day = 1;
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
    if (dec) day++;
    return day, month, year;
}

int main()
{
    int day, month, year;

    do {
        day = 0;
        month = 0; // Mise et remise à 0 des variables à chaque essai
        year = 0;

        cout << "Entrez jour (666 pour quitter le programme) : " << endl;
        cin >> day;
        cout << "Entrez Mois :" << endl;
        cin >> month;
        cout << "Entrez ann\202e : " << endl;
        cin >> year;
        if (verif(day, month, year)) { // First function call works
            cout << "Le " << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << " est une date valide ! " << endl;
        }
        dateIncrement(day, month, year); // This is skipped
        if (verif(day, month, year)) { // It goes there without calling dateIncrement...
            cout << "Le " << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << " est aussi une date valide ! " << endl;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Le " << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << " n'est pas une date valide ! " << endl;
        }
    } while (day != 666);
    return 0;
}
```

I also know that if I add a system("pause"); or a _getch(); between the first and second call, it works well, but I dont want the user to make anything after putting his date (and I also dont want to add batch in my C++).
I hope one of you can tell me why and how to solve it, thanks.

PS : I tried to say hello but this text editor wont :(

Comment: What makes you believe `dateIncrement()` isn't being called?

Comment: It is very likely that the compiler correctly deduced that your function does absolutely nothing at all, whatsoever, and simply optimized it away completely since it has no observable effects. In effect: "Nothing Of Value Was Lost".

Comment: `return day, month, year;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I recommend making a [mcve] and if making it doesn't show you what the problem is, add it to the question. Regarding `return day, month, year;`, read up on what [the comma operator really does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. A debugger allows you to control the execution of the program, slowing it down to the point where you can see exactly what the program is doing as it does it. A debugger won't find bugs for you, but by using the debugger to inspect the behaviour of the program, you can pinpoint where the program does the unexpected, and the unexpected is usually a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not being skipped. Rather, is behaving counter intuitively to what you expect. According to `dateIncrement`'s function signature

```
int dateIncrement(int day, int month, int year) {
    ...
    return day, month, year;
}
```

The function takes three ints by value. By "takes three ints by value" I mean it copies their value from main into the stack space of `dateIncrement`, where they are now new, local variables of `dateIncrement`. Any changes you make to these values in `dateIncrement` are only valid for the length of the function execution.

Your return statement `return day, month, year;` uses the comma operator. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other,

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded (although if it has class type, it won't be destroyed until the end of the containing full expression), and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins

That means that `day` and `month` do nothing, and your function returns the value of `year`. This would have some effect if you were assigning the value of of `dateIncrement` to anything in main (e.g. `year = dateIncrement(day, month, year);`) but alas you are discarding this result.

If you want a function to be able to modify parameters that you send to it (and have those changes be visible to the function that called this function), you can either pass pointers to your variables (not recommended), or pass the variables by reference.

Change your function signature to

```
void dateIncrement(int& day, int& month, int& year) {
    ...
    // this is a void function so remove your return statement
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `dateIncrement` is declared with the return type int

```
int dateIncrement(int day, int month, int year) {
```

So it can return one scalar object of the type.

However in this return statement

```
return day, month, year;
```

you are trying to return at once three objects.

Actually this return statement is equivalent to the following

```
return year;
```

because there is used the comma operator and its value is the value of the last operand.

Moreover in main you are ignoring the returned value.

```
dateIncrement(day, month, year);
```

What you need is to pass the arguments to the function by reference. It means that the function should be declared like

```
void dateIncrement(int &day, int &month, int &year) {
```

As the function has the return type void then do not specify any expression in a return statement if such a statement will be present in the function.

Pay attention to that you are determining the leap year incorrectly

```
anneeBis = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
```

And in this statement

```
feb29 = ((month == 2 && day == 29) && anneeBis);
                ^^^         ^^^
```

there are typos.